# Convergence of $\sum_n a_n$ where $0\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n(1-\beta a_n^{\alpha})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> We have a series $\sum a_n$ such that $a_n\geq0$ and $a_{n+1}\leq a_n(1-\beta a_n^{\alpha})$ ($0<\alpha<1,\beta>0$ are constant numbers). We want to prove that $\sum a_n$ converges.

We can easily have $\lim a_n=0$. But I don't have a good idea to prove the conergence of $\sum a_n$, the standard criterions didn't work well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Summing the inequalities yields $a_1\geq a_1-a_{N+1} \geq \beta \sum_{n=1}^N a_n^{2-\alpha}$. Thus $\sum_{n} a_n^{2-\alpha}$ converges. But it's not enough to conclude convergence of $\sum_{n} a_n$.

Comment: With the change in the statement of the problem, one still gets convergence of $\sum_{n} a_n^{1+\alpha}$, which is still not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n=0$ for some $n$ then $\forall k\geq n , a_{k}=0$ and there's nothing to prove. So one may assume that $\forall n, a_n\neq 0$.
I'm going to prove the claim for the worst case scenario where $a_{n+1} = a_n(1-\beta a_n^{\alpha})$. The convergence will follow in the general case by comparison.

Since $a_1\geq a_1-a_{N+1} = \beta \sum_{n=1}^N a_n^{1+\alpha}$, $\sum_n a_n^{1+\alpha}$ converges, which implies that $a_n^{1+\alpha}\to 0$, thus $a_n\to 0$.

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_{n+1}^\alpha} = \frac{1}{a_{n}^\alpha}\frac{1}{{(1-\beta a_n^\alpha)}^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{a_{n}^\alpha}(1+\alpha \beta a_n^{\alpha}+o(a_n^{\alpha})) = \frac{1}{a_{n}^\alpha} + \alpha \beta +o(1)$.

Thus $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_{n}^\alpha} = \alpha \beta n + o(n)$ which yields $\displaystyle a_n \sim (\alpha \beta)^{-1/\alpha} \frac{1}{n^{1/\alpha}}$.

Since $\frac{1}{\alpha}>1$, convergence follows.

Comment: Thank you again for the great answer!